# MySQL INSERT ... SELECT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE increment

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-update

I am having some problems with a INSERT SELECT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query. I want to to perform actions such as increment of a field in the table being inserted on for each of the rows returned by the select, some of which will need to update the same row.

Set Up:

**Table source**

```
    CREATE TABLE `source` (
  `key` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `group` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`key`)
);
```

**Table dest**

```
    CREATE TABLE `dest` (
      `dkey` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `ddata` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `dstate` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`dkey`,`dstate`)
    ) ;
```

**Source Test Values**

```
INSERT INTO `source` (`key`,`data`,`state`,`group`) VALUES (1,1,1,1);  
INSERT INTO `source` (`key`,`data`,`state`,`group`) VALUES (2,2,2,1);   
INSERT INTO `source` (`key`,`data`,`state`,`group`) VALUES (8,4,2,1);
```

Query:

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`dest` (`dkey`,`ddata`,`dstate`)   
    SELECT `group`,`data`,`state` FROM `test`.`source`   
    WHERE `group` = 1  
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  
     `ddata`= `ddata`+VALUES(`ddata`);
```

What I need it to do is when the row does not already exist in dest to create a new row with data = 1. When the row already exists I need it to increment the data.

After executing the above query the results are:

```
dkey ddata dstate  
1 1 1  
1 4 2
```

Where what I want them to be is

```
1 1 1  
1 6 2
```

Instead of adding to the previous value it is replacing it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: +1 for posting the scripts. All do as @Link does!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reproducing, I get the following results:

```
1, 1, 1
1, 6, 2
```

which seems to be right, since you have `data = 1` for `state = 1` and `data = 2, 4` for `state = 2` in your source data.

Why are you expecting `2` in the first record?

Comment: I'm not. I made a mistake in copying it from the test database I created. Thank you for pointing it out. 
The problem I am having is with the second row however. Thanks @Quassnoi

Comment: @Link: I cannot reproduce the problem. Are you sure it's not from the test database as well?

Comment: Still not sure what was the problem, but I seemed to have fixed it. Actually the problem doesn't seem like it was with the INSERT SELECT UPDATE code, but I think it was more of a problem with my column references. Always use fully qualified column names . >>